# What are $H(i\omega)$, $H(s)$ and $H(z)$ called?

Tags: filters

What are the Fourier-, Laplace- and Z-transforms of the impulse response of a filter called? I've seen $H(s)$ referred to as the system function or transfer function, what about $H(i\omega)$ and the discretized $H(z)$?

Comment: The nomenclature depends on which authority you cite.  See some of the comments following my answer to [this question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/270/what-is-the-relation-between-the-psds-of-filter-input-and-output-called-r-y/273#273)

Comment: @Dilip: Interesting, I think your comment there contains the answer (except for $H(z)$).

Comment: A comment made by someone else in that thread claims that $H(z)$ is also called the transfer function by some authorities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would consider them to all be 'transfer' or 'system' functions. 
Those two names are interchangable, but in control theory books I see then listed more as transfer functions rather than system functions.

The domain you are in, whether it be fourier, laplace, Z or time, isn't entirely relevant to the name in that respect.

Comment: I agree with your assessment. I don't think nomenclature specifics are all that important, but I've typically heard the $H(j\omega)$ version called the "frequency response."

Comment: true... I would consider "Frequency response" another name for it.
H(jw) is a transfer function, that more specifically is a frequency response